# Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine which asia region is nearest to Singapore?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine which asia region is nearest to Singapore?
I tried all 3 region and ping it but all shows US California location...

Answer (score 3):

There is only one region in Asia (asia-east1). However, there are 3 zones (asia-east1-a, ...). All three zones are in the same geographic location. None of them are "closer" to any location than the others.

Picking a zone based on location is probably not what you want to be doing anyways. Instead, you should try to connect from different locations and look at ping, traceroute, speedtest, etc. A place that is geographically closer may not be closer based on routing. I at one point had to pick an AWS region for a VPN available to programmers in China. We found US-East had the best connection even though Singapore (not sure if Tokyo existed at the time) was obviously geographically closer.

Comment: How do I choose region? I am able to choose zone from quick deploy and found out that even though it stated ASIA when I check the IP it shows in California

Comment: Each zone is part of a region. If you use zone asia-east1-a, you will be in region asia-east1-a. The IP information is simply wrong. Google is in California and all of its IP addresses are registered there. In terms of geography, all asia-east1 zones are equally far from Singapore and are the closest zones.

Comment: asia-east1-a is in Taiwan, see [Google Cloud Platform location](http://www.quora.com/Where-are-the-Google-Cloud-Platforms-regions-physically-located). Use the method describe there , we can probably locate all regions.

Answer (score 3):

**2017 update**: Google Cloud Platform now has a `asia-southeast1` region in Singapore itself.

See: https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/